# refresh page once only in body not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have add this code in the body tag. the web page keeps on refreshing like a loop.

```
<body onload="window.location.reload()">
```

I tried searching for a Javascript code or for a condition that will make it stop. I found a ways to do it but when I test it, they are not working.

I'm sorry but it is not possible to refresh the page 1 time once the page is completely loaded.

I want only once load page when i open the page. Can any one please tell me

Comment: the real queation is: Why do you want to do this? | What do you want to do, that you need to refresh a page right after it has been loaded?

Comment: People trying to do this are usually trying to prevent people seeing stale content and need to use HTTP cache control headers and not anything related to JavaScript.

Comment: Seems strange, to first load a page and then immediately reload it? What should there be on the page the second time that will not be there the first? Please tell us more.

Comment: Yes @Mischa after page open my page not loaded fully, means i have one form,after click edit button the edit form values showing old values so that if i refresh page it is showing all new values so that i need refresh page after open page

Comment: I have one form.in that form edit button is available. after click edit button then form edit page is loaded.if i edit form after save again it showing correct data.if i click again edit button showing old data.If i reload then it showing new data

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

- When the page loads, read the URL.
- If there is **no** fragment identifier (e.g., `#reloaded`), add the fragment identifier and reload the page.
- If there **is** a fragment identifier (e.g., `#reloaded`), don't reload.

This isn't necessarily a fool-proof technique, but might serve your purposes.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.hash !== "reloaded") {
        window.location = window.location + "#reloaded";
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use this code in my page,how can i add this code in my page please tell me

Comment: its not working ...loop loading again and again .i want load only once